# Why does event.pageX not work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, compatibility

I wrote some code and tested it in Opera - everything worked fine. When I open the same code in Firefox it doesn't work. Chrome and Edge work also fine. I get the error message "event is not defined". The official Mozzila devolper site says event.pageX is working: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX . 
Here is my code:

```
<script>
function funcpos(){
    document.getElementById('layer').style.left = event.pageX;
    document.getElementById('layer').style.top = event.pageY;
}
function trans(){
    var div = document.getElementById('txt1');
    div.className = "trans";
}
function norm(){
    var div = document.getElementById('txt1');
    div.className = "norm";
}
</script>
<style>
p.trans{
opacity:0}
p.norm{
text-shadow:1px 1px 8px #000000;
color:#EFEFEF;
opacity:1}
</style>
<div id=layer style="background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><p id=txt1 class=trans>Some Text</p></div>
<img onmousemove='funcpos()' id=img1 src=bild.png onmouseenter="norm()" onmouseout="trans()"/>
```

How do i get to run this code to run in Firefox?

Comment: The global `event` object is a proprietary object from Microsoft/IE and not part of the standard ([`window.event` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event). You can (and should) not rely on its presence. The correct way would be to use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Just to add to what Andreas has said, when you refer to `event` by default it refers to `window.event` - which is not supported in Firefox. The simple fix would be to modify the img declaration to pass the event: `onmousemove='funcpos(event)'`.